# Are functions like strip_tags() and trim() UTF-8 aware?

Tags: utf-8, php-5.3

I'm wondering whether functions like `strip_tags()` and `trim()` UTF-8 aware?

I found this on the web, but I'm not sure about it:

> `strip_tags()`: multi-byte UTF-8 characters contain no byte sequences that resemble less-than or greater-than symbols.
>
> `trim()`: multi-byte UTF-8 characters contain no byte sequences that resemble white space.

If it's true, using those functions with an UTF-8 string could lead to a corrupted/illegible string.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the descriptions you quoted mean just the opposite. Because utf8 multi-byte characters DON'T contains whitespace, or lt/gt, or any other byte < 0x80, you can safely use those functions on utf8 strings. That's the beauty of utf8!

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand it! I missed the ‘no’ in the ‘no byte’, now I get it. :P (I understood this for functions like stripslashes and other, but this description confused me).